# How is the inverse Laplace-Borel transform defined?

Tags: laplace-transform

How is the inverse Laplace-Borel transform defined?

Si $\mu\in (\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C}))^{\ast}$ (The dual space of the entire functions or analytic functionals) then the Laplace-Borel $\mathcal{L}\mu(\xi)\equiv \langle \mu(z),\mathrm{e}^{z\xi}\rangle$ is an isomorphism between $(\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C}))^{\ast}$ and $\text{Exp}(\mathbb{C})$ (the entire functions of exponential type). If $f(z)\in \text{Exp}(\mathbb{C})$. How is $\mathcal{L}^{-1}f(z)$ defined? What analytical functional is it?

Thanks.

Comment: Is [Borel transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachbin%27s_theorem#Borel_transform) relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to Treves "Topological vector spaces, distributions and kernels". See also [Borel-Fourier transform.](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Fourier-Borel_transform)

Analytic functional is a continuous linear functional on the space of entire functions. Textbook provides details re. topologies on relevant spaces etc.

There is reverse formula provided:
$$
  f(\xi) = \langle\mu_f(z), e^{z\xi}\rangle\in \mathrm{Exp(\mathbb{C}})
$$
where $\mu_f (F) = \sum_n a_n f^{(n)}(0)$  given $F(z) = \sum_n a_n z^n\in \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C}).$

Comment: But if $\mathcal{L}(\mu)(\xi)=\langle \mu(z),\mathrm{e}^{z\xi}\rangle=:f(\xi)$
then $\mathcal{L}(\mu_f)(\xi)=\mathcal{L}(\mu)(\xi)$?

Comment: Yes, $\mu=\mu_f.$ Given $\mu$ (acting on holomorphic functions) one constructs $f(\xi)\in \mathrm{Exp(\mathbb{C}})$ and then formula shows how function $f(\xi)$ acts on holomorphic $F$ i.e. reconstructs $\mu.$

Comment: How interesting is this. That formula appears explicitly in Topological vector spaces, distributions and kernels? thank you

Comment: Yes, formula is explicitly mentioned.

Comment: Query: Is there any integral representation of the inverse Laplace transform? I ask it with the analogy of the Fourier transform and in order to be able to define an operator $\partial_z \mu=\mathcal{L}^{-1}(\xi\mathcal{L}(\mu)(\xi) )$ ($\mu$ analytic functional) from its symbol $\xi$. Is there something like that? thank you.

Comment: @eraldcoil If $f(\xi) = \mathcal{L}(\mu) = \langle\mu(z), e^{z\xi}\rangle$ then for $g(\xi) = \xi f(\xi)$ one can compute $g^{(n)}(0) = nf^{(n-1)}(0) + f^{(n)}(0), n \ge 0$ using Leibniz rule. Corresponding analytic functional $\mu_g = \mathcal{L}^{-1}(g)$ would give $\sum a_ng^{(n)}(0)$ on $F=\sum_n a_nz^n\in \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C}).$ Also taking $F=z^n$ one obtains $f^{(n)}(0) = \langle\mu(z), z^n\rangle.$